# Send daily emails with Springboot - JHipster

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I want to send daily emails to all the users of my database.
I use Springboot and JHipster in the back-end.

In the rest controller, I have a GET request (which was automatically created by JHipster) :

```
/**
 * GET  /users : get all users.
 * 
 * @param pageable the pagination information
 * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK) and with body all users
 * @throws URISyntaxException if the pagination headers couldnt be generated
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/users",
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public ResponseEntity<List<ManagedUserDTO>> getAllUsers(Pageable pageable)
    throws URISyntaxException {
    Page<User> page = userRepository.findAll(pageable);
    List<ManagedUserDTO> managedUserDTOs = page.getContent().stream()
        .map(ManagedUserDTO::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(page, "/api/users");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(managedUserDTOs, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I also have a MailService which is already used for account validation and password reset :

```
/**
* Service for sending e-mails.
* <p>
* We use the @Async annotation to send e-mails asynchronously.
* </p>
*/
@Service
public class MailService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MailService.class);

    private static final String USER = "user";
    private static final String BASE_URL = "baseUrl";

    @Inject
    private JHipsterProperties jHipsterProperties;

    @Inject
    private JavaMailSenderImpl javaMailSender;

    @Inject
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Inject
    private SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine;

    @Async
    public void sendEmail(String to, String subject, String content, boolean isMultipart, boolean isHtml) {
        log.debug("Send e-mail[multipart '{}' and html '{}'] to '{}' with subject '{}' and content={}",
            isMultipart, isHtml, to, subject, content);

        // Prepare message using a Spring helper
        MimeMessage mimeMessage = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        try {
            MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, isMultipart, CharEncoding.UTF_8);
            message.setTo(to);
            message.setFrom(jHipsterProperties.getMail().getFrom());
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(content, isHtml);
            javaMailSender.send(mimeMessage);
            log.debug("Sent e-mail to User '{}'", to);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("E-mail could not be sent to user '{}', exception is: {}", to, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Async
    public void sendActivationEmail(User user, String baseUrl) {
        user.setLangKey("en");
        log.debug("Sending activation e-mail to '{}'", user.getEmail());
        Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(user.getLangKey());
        Context context = new Context(locale);
        context.setVariable(USER, user);
        context.setVariable(BASE_URL, baseUrl);
        String content = templateEngine.process("activationEmail", context);
        String subject = messageSource.getMessage("email.activation.title", null, locale);
        sendEmail(user.getEmail(), subject, content, false, true);
    }

    @Async
    public void sendCreationEmail(User user, String baseUrl) {
        log.debug("Sending creation e-mail to '{}'", user.getEmail());
        Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(user.getLangKey());
        Context context = new Context(locale);
        context.setVariable(USER, user);
        context.setVariable(BASE_URL, baseUrl);
        String content = templateEngine.process("creationEmail", context);
        String subject = messageSource.getMessage("email.activation.title", null, locale);
        sendEmail(user.getEmail(), subject, content, false, true);
    }

    @Async
    public void sendPasswordResetMail(User user, String baseUrl) {
        log.debug("Sending password reset e-mail to '{}'", user.getEmail());
        Locale locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(user.getLangKey());
        Context context = new Context(locale);
        context.setVariable(USER, user);
        context.setVariable(BASE_URL, baseUrl);
        String content = templateEngine.process("passwordResetEmail", context);
        String subject = messageSource.getMessage("email.reset.title", null, locale);
        sendEmail(user.getEmail(), subject, content, false, true);
    }

}
```

I know how to make requests from the front-end and to connect it with the back-end, but here, what I need, is to do a request from the back to the back.

I also don't understand what the Pageable object is for and how to create it since it is an interface :

```
public interface Pageable {

    int getPageNumber();

    int getPageSize();

    int getOffset();

    Sort getSort();

    Pageable next();

    Pageable previousOrFirst();

    Pageable first();

    boolean hasPrevious();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vinzee,

All you need is a new service using scheduling. See below excerpt

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ScheduleService {
   //send mails daily at 1am
   @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 1 * * ?")
   public void sendDailyMails{
      //call userRepository.findAll
      //create mail content or use a template (e.g. Velocity)
      //for each user call MailService.sendMail 
      //passing content, to(user.getEmail()), from, etc;
  }
}
```